# Compare two array of objects and update element in main array - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects (main array) and a filtered list. They have a selected property which has a value of true. I need to compare both of them and update the selected property to false if it is not present in the other array.

This is my implementation.

```js
const data = [{
    color: "red",
    value: "#f00",
    selected: true
  },
  {
    color: "green",
    value: "#0f0",
    selected: true
  },
  {
    color: "blue",
    value: "#00f",
    selected: true
  },
  {
    color: "cyan",
    value: "#0ff",
    selected: true
  },
  {
    color: "magenta",
    value: "#f0f",
    selected: true
  },
  {
    color: "yellow",
    value: "#ff0",
    selected: true
  },
  {
    color: "black",
    value: "#000",
    selected: true
  }
]

const filtered = [{
  color: "magenta",
  value: "#f0f",
  selected: true
}, {
  color: "green",
  value: "#0f0",
  selected: true
}, {
  color: "black",
  value: "#000",
  selected: true
}]

data.forEach(item => {
 for(var key in filtered) {
   if(filtered[key]['value'] === item.value) {
     item.selected = false
    }
  }
})

console.log(data)
```

The expected output should be opposite of that.

```
    [
      {
        "color": "red",
        "value": "#f00",
        "selected": false
      },
      {
        "color": "green",
        "value": "#0f0",
        "selected": true
      },
      {
        "color": "blue",
        "value": "#00f",
        "selected": false
      },
      {
        "color": "cyan",
        "value": "#0ff",
        "selected": false
      },
      {
        "color": "magenta",
        "value": "#f0f",
        "selected": true
      },
      {
        "color": "yellow",
        "value": "#ff0",
        "selected": false
      },
      {
        "color": "black",
        "value": "#000",
        "selected": true
      }
    ]
```

Please advice. Is there a more better to achieve this?

P.S: I can use lodash as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you intend to compare based on `value`, or based on a combination of `color` and `value`?

Comment: In my exact scenario, it will be based on a id, but I used value just for this data

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array containing the values from the filtered array, and then iterate through your main data array and see if individual items contains values in the filtered array:

```
const filteredValues = filtered.map(item => item.value);
data.forEach(item => {
  item.selected = filteredValues.includes(item.value);
});
```

The advantage of this method is that you get rid of doing nested iterations (basically `O(n^2)` complexity).

```js
const data = [{
    color: "red",
    value: "#f00",
    selected: true
  },
  {
    color: "green",
    value: "#0f0",
    selected: true
  },
  {
    color: "blue",
    value: "#00f",
    selected: true
  },
  {
    color: "cyan",
    value: "#0ff",
    selected: true
  },
  {
    color: "magenta",
    value: "#f0f",
    selected: true
  },
  {
    color: "yellow",
    value: "#ff0",
    selected: true
  },
  {
    color: "black",
    value: "#000",
    selected: true
  }
]

const filtered = [{
  color: "magenta",
  value: "#f0f",
  selected: true
}, {
  color: "green",
  value: "#0f0",
  selected: true
}, {
  color: "black",
  value: "#000",
  selected: true
}]

const filteredValues = filtered.map(item => item.value);
data.forEach(item => {
  item.selected = filteredValues.includes(item.value);
})

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Hey Terry, I need to have true for all the one's in the filtered list and false which are not in the filtered list.

Comment: @a2441918 My bad. Updated my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about to add `foreach` and check the `item` with `filtered` array as shown here:

```js
const data = [{
    color: "red",
    value: "#f00",
    selected: true
  },
  {
    color: "green",
    value: "#0f0",
    selected: true
  },
  {
    color: "blue",
    value: "#00f",
    selected: true
  },
  {
    color: "cyan",
    value: "#0ff",
    selected: true
  },
  {
    color: "magenta",
    value: "#f0f",
    selected: true
  },
  {
    color: "yellow",
    value: "#ff0",
    selected: true
  },
  {
    color: "black",
    value: "#000",
    selected: true
  }
]

const filtered = [{
  color: "magenta",
  value: "#f0f",
  selected: true
}, {
  color: "green",
  value: "#0f0",
  selected: true
}, {
  color: "black",
  value: "#000",
  selected: true
}];
var filteredData = [];

data.forEach(item => {
    var isSelected = 0;
    filtered.forEach(filterItem => {
        if(item.value === filterItem.value) {
            isSelected = 1;
        }
    });
  
    if (isSelected == 0) {
        item.selected = false;
    }
    filteredData.push(item); 
});

console.log(filteredData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement as soon as you find a match you should set the selected value to true. Then you should break out of the loop. Moreover, if the object from the data list is not present in the filtered list you should set its selected to false.

```js
const data = [{
    color: "red",
    value: "#f00",
    selected: true
  },
  {
    color: "green",
    value: "#0f0",
    selected: true
  },
  {
    color: "blue",
    value: "#00f",
    selected: true
  },
  {
    color: "cyan",
    value: "#0ff",
    selected: true
  },
  {
    color: "magenta",
    value: "#f0f",
    selected: true
  },
  {
    color: "yellow",
    value: "#ff0",
    selected: true
  },
  {
    color: "black",
    value: "#000",
    selected: true
  }
]

const filtered = [{
  color: "magenta",
  value: "#f0f",
  selected: true
}, {
  color: "green",
  value: "#0f0",
  selected: true
}, {
  color: "black",
  value: "#000",
  selected: true
}]

data.forEach(item => {
 for(var key in filtered) {
   if(filtered[key]['value'] === item.value) {
     item.selected = true;
      break;
    }
    else {
      item.selected = false;
    
  }
  }
})

console.log(data)
```